# How to combine two video streams coming from two ip cameras as one stream over ip using http or rtsp protocol? I want to use gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, ip-camera, stereo-3d

I am having two ip cameras which gives mjpeg streams. I want to treat these cameras as left and right camera for getting stereo.

I had already worked on separate left and right cameras using GStreamer. It worked perfectly alright.

Now I want to synchronize play using single stream only. For that I want to combine these two ip camera streams as single stream and then at player side I want to decode it.
So this problem will be divided into two steps
FIRST get single stream out off two ip camera streams, here left and right sources may be tagged with "left" and "right" tag etc.
SECOND get each stream using tags, decode it and show as left and right images to get active stereo.

It is similar to video3d, but I want to use active stereo and not passive one.
I want to use GStreamer as it is cross platform, but I am new to GStreamer.
If you can give GStreamer pipeline for FIRST step and logic for SECOND state it will be helpful for me.